# How can I travel so that I am never lost?

Tags: planning, international-travel, solo-travel

What should I factor in preparations so that when I travel, I am never lost ?

Edit: I am specifically interested in travelling within Australia by road or taking direct flights between Australia to the USA.

Comment: From the sounds of it, if it was an explosion or  disintegration in-flight, practically *nothing* you could do would have prevented anything :/

Comment: One could always come up with the situation where your body will be irretrievable

Comment: Leaving the Malay airlines aside, is there nothing else one could do to be never lost during international travel?

Comment: edited to make it less broad

Comment: @Flimzy Thats insightful. Do you have any answers for what the question asks :  "travelling within Australia by road or taking direct flights between Australia to the USA"

Comment: I suppose: Use a map. Read street signs. Learn to navigate by the stars. Learn to navigate by the sun and moon.  Carry a compass. Use a GPS. Don't go anywhere without a guide. Leave breadcrumbs everywhere you go... The possible answers are endless.

Comment: Downvoters - don't forget to comment the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Lost as in "I don't know where I am" or lost as in "missing". If it's the first there are different degrees of lost, you can not know where you are but still have a way to get back to where you're going.

Comment: @SpaceDog To some extent a person can really go 'missing' only if someone has been looking for them so I think its a shade of both 'I dont know where I am' and 'missing'

Comment: @happybuddha understood, thanks -- in that case I don't think I can improve on the answer below but I'll have a think about it.

Answer (score 3):

One way might be to carry a [PLB (Personal Locator Beacon)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distress_radiobeacon) which is essentially a GPS receiver with an emergency radio transmitter, that can be activated manually or (on some models) automatically by immersion in water. These are monitored using a global satellite network and so in theory will work anywhere in the world. Certainly in Australia and the USA the search and rescue organisations understand PLBs.

Such a device is unlikely to help much in case of an emergency aboard a commercial flight, because (a) the aircraft probably has better emergency location systems anyway, and (b) you probably won't be permitted to turn on the device during flight because it has a radio transmission function.

Under non-emergency circumstances, a pretty good method is to use a smartphone with an app like Apple's "Find My Friends" or Google Latitude to keep in touch with family and friends at home. Particularly if you have cellular data service (and enough cell phone battery), this will allow people to find your location (at least, the location *of your phone*) quickly.

Finally, having a phone with maps helps *you* to avoid getting lost.

Comment: How deep does PLB work?

Comment: @Karlson: Probably not very deep, ones that are intended for a aquatic environment are usually designed to float. They might be naturally buoyant, or have a pressure-activated release mechanism.

Comment: If your plane explodes, however, it may be separated from you or disabled altogether.  Plus > 100 feet depth with ocean currents and good luck.